# Tensorflow make assign op an explicit dependency for computing a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to be able to implicitly run an `assign` Op every single time I run another tensor which depends on the `tf.Variable` which is changed during the `assign` Op. I don't want to run the `assign` Op manually  every single step. I tried 2 different approaches. Here is a simple example illustration:

```
target_prob     = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
target_var      = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32)
init_target_var = tf.assign(target_var, tf.zeros_like(target_prob),
                            validate_shape=False)

# First approach
with tf.control_dependencies([init_target_var]):
  result = target_prob + target_var

# Second approach
# [target_var] = tf.tuple([target_var], control_inputs=[init_target_var])
# result = target_prob + target_var

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
res1 = sess.run(result, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([10, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
res2 = sess.run(result, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([12, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
```

Both fail with the error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [12,2] vs. [10,2]` when `res2` is being computed. It all works if I instead do:

```
res1 = sess.run(result, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([10, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
sess.run(init_target_var, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([12, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
res2 = sess.run(result, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([12, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
```

But again, running `init_target_var` explicitly is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

P.S. The above is just a simplistic example. My final goal is to use the resulting tensor from [tf.scatter_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_add) which unfortunately requires a mutable tensor as input.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, I was actually using the wrong tensor when computing `result`. The correct code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

target_prob         = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
tmp_var             = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32, validate_shape=False)
target_var          = tf.assign(tmp_var, tf.zeros_like(target_prob), validate_shape=False)

with tf.control_dependencies([target_var]):
  result = target_prob + target_var

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

res1 = sess.run(result, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([10, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
res2 = sess.run(result, feed_dict={target_prob: np.ones([12, 2], dtype=np.float32)})
```